# Document tags not displaying in search results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, search-results

I have created a Managed Metadata service & done a full crawl. After full crawl was finished, I started testing in my search site. Still tags keywords are not displayed in the search results.

Please help me,do I still need to configure something in Central Administration?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the keyword fields queryable in the search schema.

I have tried to descripe it further. Unfortunately my SharePoint is in danish. But when this is set I can search for the tag by searching like this. owstaxIdVirksomheder:aon and then get documents with the "aon" tag.

[image: Searchable and querable has to be set]